# Remove Part of String Perl

Tags: string, perl, str-replace

I have this in perl

```
  return "$file->{srv_cgi_url}/dl.cgi/$hash/$fname";
```

where

```
$file->{srv_cgi_url}
```

returns

```
http://s1.site.com/cgi-bin/
```

how can I remove the trailing /cgi-bin/ from the string? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
my $new = $file->{srv_cgi_url};
$new =~ s{/cgi-bin/}{};
```

That is all. See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

While substitution can work, it’s fragile and difficult to extend and maintain. I strenuously recommend learng to use [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI), [URI::QueryParam](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aQueryParam), and [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass) instead (the last is not used in this example but important and related).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use URI;

my $file;
$file->{srv_cgi_url} = "http://s1.site.com/cgi-bin/";

my $srv_cgi_uri = URI->new( $file->{srv_cgi_url} );

my $hash = "some";
my $fname = "path.ext";

$srv_cgi_uri->path("/dl.cgi/$hash/$fname");

print $srv_cgi_uri, "\n";

__END__
http://s1.site.com/dl.cgi/some/path.ext
```